# Irregular rectangle shape

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make a rectangle (preferable without using canvas or background images) that looks somewhat like the blue box in the image below. Note that the shape has irregular edges.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

```
div {
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing or the question you want to ask because all you've done is tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Cool. Then make it :)

Comment: The problem is that i have no idea where to start. I dont want to use background images-

Comment: basically share your code what you have tried

Comment: @JulianEspinosa Thanks, your help means the world.

Comment: @tech2017 done..

Comment: @csm_dev the question is how i should do it.

Comment: did CSS Masking help?

Comment: yes it did the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for CSS Masking and Shapes Modules

Dig here: [CSS Masking on html5rocks.com](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

Also here is a good explanation with use cases: [Creating Non-Rectangular Layouts With CSS Shapes](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/)

You can create any shape you want, apply it to anything you want: image, background, text, another form - no limits. Moreover, you can animate it!

And here is a good service to crop such things with mouse: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

NOTE, that not every browser may support that at the moment: http://caniuse.com/css-clip-path/embed

And yes, no SVG or images needed - flexible, dynamic, css-only trick.

```css
.box{
  width: 400px; height: 120px; background:black; position:relative
}
.poly{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  background:#2abcd0;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(6% 13%, 24% 13%, 36% 12%, 53% 12%, 61% 12%, 65% 13%, 76% 12%, 95% 10%, 95% 44%, 96% 88%, 80% 86%, 69% 86%, 65% 88%, 46% 88%, 21% 88%, 6% 89%, 5% 86%, 5% 80%, 5% 40%, 5% 16%);
clip-path: polygon(6% 13%, 24% 13%, 36% 12%, 53% 12%, 61% 12%, 65% 13%, 76% 12%, 95% 10%, 95% 44%, 96% 88%, 80% 86%, 69% 86%, 65% 88%, 46% 88%, 21% 88%, 6% 89%, 5% 86%, 5% 80%, 5% 40%, 5% 16%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="poly"></div>
</div>
```

And without black box:

```css
.poly{
  width:400px;
  height:120px;
  background:#2abcd0;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(6% 13%, 24% 13%, 36% 12%, 53% 12%, 61% 12%, 65% 13%, 76% 12%, 95% 10%, 95% 44%, 96% 88%, 80% 86%, 69% 86%, 65% 88%, 46% 88%, 21% 88%, 6% 89%, 5% 86%, 5% 80%, 5% 40%, 5% 16%);
clip-path: polygon(6% 13%, 24% 13%, 36% 12%, 53% 12%, 61% 12%, 65% 13%, 76% 12%, 95% 10%, 95% 44%, 96% 88%, 80% 86%, 69% 86%, 65% 88%, 46% 88%, 21% 88%, 6% 89%, 5% 86%, 5% 80%, 5% 40%, 5% 16%);
}
```

```html
<div class="poly"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i dont want the box? only the blue.

Comment: Then don't use the box, added snippet

Comment: Yes, but then it gets offset.

Comment: yes, which is controlled by parameters of css polygon. Now it has at least 6% offset

Answer (score 1):

Divs are and have always been rectangular.  Though you can make some complicated shapes if you have the time to individually trace it out using coordinates.  Check out [this page](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) for a list of shapes you can easily put together, and useing these same ideas you can build your own more complicated shapes.

You may end up with something like...

```
shape-outside: polygon(170.67px 291.00px,126.23px 347.56px,139.79px 417.11px,208.92px 466.22px,302.50px 482.97px,343.67px 474.47px,446.33px 452.00px,443.63px 246.82px,389.92px 245.63px,336.50px 235.26px,299.67px 196.53px,259.33px 209.53px,217.00px 254.76px);
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/) as well.  She talks about [shapses to poly](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/)  a tool which makes the process of making custom shapes much more manageable.

Comment: I was just demonstrating the idea, (I actually pulled that snippet from someones website)  The idea is still what is important, and you can convert it to a scalable model as you need.

Comment: Finally someone that actually reads the question. Thanks! will look into this.